# Increase performance of R for-loops after pre-allocation of data structures

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have read a bit about increasing performance of for loops in r, but I am still stuck with one taking ~140secs.

I will start with the code:

```
matrix <- matrix(NA, length(register[,1]), length(AK), dimnames = list(register[,1], AK))

data.cleaned <- data[data$FO %in% register[,1],]
rownames(data.cleaned) <- paste(1:nrow(data.cleaned))


for (i in 1 : nrow(data.cleaned)) {
  for (j in 1 : nrow(matrix)) {

    if (data.cleaned$FO[i] == rownames(matrix)[j]) {
        for (k in 1 : ncol(matrix)) {

              if (data.cleaned$AK[i] == colnames(matrix)[k])
                  {matrix[j,k] <- 1}

      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't deliver any reproducible example. That data.cleaned data frame is frame, which includes around 11000 rows. In each row there is an observation for FO (main category) and for AK (sub category for FO) (two different variables).

The goal is fill matrix[i,j] with 1 if there in one row is the corresponding FO and AK observation.

Does this make sense. Please also comment, if I need to specify or can write the post in a more clear/better way

Comment: For loops themselves are not very performant in R, try to replace as many of them with vectorized functions, etc.

Comment: How many seconds the code from my answer need on your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step:
You can set

```
cnames.m <- colnames(matrix)
```

before you go into the loops. At the right place you can do

```
if (data.cleaned$AK[i] == cnames.m[k]) matrix[j,k] <- 1
```

Second step:
The inner loop is identical with

```
matrix[j, data.cleaned$AK[i] == cnames.m] <- 1
```

So there is no need to loop with `k`.

```
matrix <- matrix(NA, length(register[,1]), length(AK), dimnames = list(register[,1], AK))

data.cleaned <- data[data$FO %in% register[,1],]
rownames(data.cleaned) <- paste(1:nrow(data.cleaned))

cnames.m <- colnames(matrix)
for (i in 1 : nrow(data.cleaned)) for (j in 1 : nrow(matrix)) 
    if (data.cleaned$FO[i] == rownames(matrix)[j]) matrix[j, data.cleaned$AK[i] == cnames.m] <- 1
```

---

one remark about object names:
it is not a good idea to name a matrix `matrix` (would you name a dog `Dog`?)